# jstree: create new node not working

Tags: javascript, jstree

```
$('#create-blank-node').click(function () {
    $('#treepanel').jstree("create", $("#parent_node"), "first", "new node");
});
```

"treepanel" is a div id which is a tree.
This function is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue, it should be 'create_node' instead of 'create': like this

```
$('#create-blank-node').click(function () {
    $('#treepanel').jstree("create_node", $("#parent_node"), "first", {attr : {id: newNodeId}, data: newPartName});
});
```

It is worked correctly. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

add a new node

```
$("#categories_jstree").jstree('create_node', '#', {'id' : '1944', 'text' : 'nosde1'}, 'last');
```

where # is a parent node id (empty_now)

add a nested node for node1

```
$("#categories_jstree").jstree('create_node', '#1944', {'id' : '1945', 'text' : 'subnode1_1'});
```

the #1944 - parent node id

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide your tree structure? Looking at your snippet, I'm assuming that "parent_node" is a valid node within the tree (already exists) and doesn't have any rules (types plugin) that would limit it from receiving a new child node. Are you binding to any functions in your tree and doing custom work?

What happens if you just do this?:

```
$('#treepanel').jstree("create");
```